# Change number format for Grails app

Tags: formatting, grails-2.0, gsp

I have a problem. I have to fill a form (in the create page) with many inputs for numbers and most of them are greater than 1000 (one thousand) so when I write the numbers they don't have any format (I know it's obvious), then after the creating, when the show page is shown it can be seen that the numbers have a format (example: create page: 1000.5 => show page: 1,000.5). When I invoke the edit page to edit the record the inputs of the form are filled with formatted numbers just like happens in the show page and it's producing errors in some result fields because I have to do some calculations after the page is loaded.

How to keep the numbers loaded in edit page (and show page too) without formatting? It doesn't matter for me if the solution must be applied for all my application, I have to deal with a lot of numbers so it would be better.

The show.gsp view doesn't use g.formatNumber, but (as example):

In the _form.gsp view (so in the create.gsp and edit gsp) this is the code for the same field:

Currently these are the results:

[image: change format]

I need the retrieved numbers in the edit.gsp view to don't have any format. Or, if it is possible, to change the default application number formatting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the views snipsets where number are printed. And verify what grails.views.default.codec are you using

Comment: The show.gsp view doesn't use g.formatNumber, but (as example):
`<g:fieldValue bean="${liquidacionDeEstanoInstance}" field="totalLiquidoPagable"/>`

In the _form.gsp view (so in the create.gsp and edit gsp) this is the code for the same field:
`<g:field name="totalLiquidoPagable" value="${fieldValue(bean: liquidacionDeEstanoInstance, field: 'totalLiquidoPagable')}" required=""/>`. The encoding: `grails.views.default.codec = "none"`

Comment: Hi. This is the version I'm using: `grails-2.2.3`

Answer (score 0):

g:fieldValue apply number conversion

Take a look to [source file](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/dfe1d4aef5707ebd7c45e135b70d1bf9341eaa00/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/ValidationTagLib.groovy) line 86 and line 465.

I think the problem is that you are using g:fieldValue and g:input together. You have to choose one of the two.

If you use fieldValue in the **_form.gsp** write:

```
<input type="text" value="${fieldValue(bean: liquidacionDeEstanoInstance, field: 'totalLiquidoPagable')}" />
```

and not use g:fied.

Or, second choise, use g:field but not use g:fieldValue as follow:

```
<g:field name="totalLiquidoPagable" value="${liquidacionDeEstanoInstance.totalLiquidoPagable)}" required=""/>
```

Try put in the form this code:

```
 Script output: ${liquidacionDeEstanoInstance.totalLiquidoPagable}
 Tagscript output: <%= liquidacionDeEstanoInstance.totalLiquidoPagable >
 Grails tag output: ${fieldValue(bean: liquidacionDeEstanoInstance, field: 'totalLiquidoPagable')}
```

I'm aspecting to have

```
Script outout: 1000.5 (or if you have an app level converted configured 1,000.5)
Tagscript output: 1000.5
Grails tag output: 1,000.5
```

Tell me your results

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't solve my problem. I changed some parts of my code using the code you've suggested but the result is the same. I'm developing an application for the mining field so I have to deal mainly with numbers, a lot of numbers so to change every line code where a number is handled will mean a lot of work too. That's why I'm looking for a way (if it's possible) to establish the default number format for my application. By the way, the code I'm using is the code that was automatically generated.

Comment: Grails tags (g:..) formats numbers before output it to html according to your locale settings. You can change locale settings change number ouput format. Or if you want total control do not use grails tags but simpli output values. See anwer addendum

Comment: That works, although I've already tried that. The problem is that I have to change many lines of code in my views in order to have them working correctly with the calculations. I gave up (at least for now) on trying to remove any number formatting. But I found a solution, I set the default locale for my application and I wrote a JavaScript function to remove the colon (for example: `12,345.60` to `12345.60` because the JavaScript `parseFloat` function was returning `12` instead of `12345.60`) and now all the calculations are correct.

Comment: Using javascript to remove colon is horrible but if you are happy this way who am I to questionate!? :)

Comment: Definitely I'm not happy with this solution but what other chances do I have? What I don't want to do is to change every line of code in my GSPs to have the correct result (numbers without formatting). I have to deal with 18 domain classes to represent the minerals and its operations and every domain class have approximately 60 number fields.

Comment: Why not search and replace with the aid of Regular Expressions!? :)